# Trigger with NOCOUNT outputs 1 or more row(s) affected when no datatable rows were changed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger, nocount

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have triggers on a view, with the intent of allowing my users to perform DML actions on it like any other table. These triggers have `SET NOCOUNT ON` and have many `IF...RAISERROR(...) RETURN` statements to catch logical errors. I noticed that even when a trigger is returned without affecting any underlying tables, SSMS outputs "n or more row(s) affected" where n is the number of rows that would have been affected in the view. So, I tested the following simple trigger, with the same results:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.triggerViewTest 
ON dbo.viewTest
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF 1 != 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('No rows should be affected!', 16, 1)
        RETURN
    END
END

INSERT INTO dbo.viewTest (columnA) VALUES (1)
```

And SSMS prints `1 row(s) affected`.

How do I suppress this output?

Comment: That's the row count from the *insert*, not the row count by any actions taken by the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will prevent this message returned to console.
It is related with session settings not with the trigger code

```
set nocount on
insert into viewTest select...
set nocount off
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because `It is related with session settings...` is the reason for this behavior, and it turns out the only way to prevent that message is to `THROW` an error.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here based on what @Eralper said; this message is from the session settings and not from the trigger. So, the only way to prevent the message is to `THROW` an error, which cancels that session (`RAISERROR()` does not cancel the session). The following trigger does not display `n row(s) affected`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.triggerViewTest 
ON dbo.viewTest
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF 1 != 0
    BEGIN
        ;THROW 50000, 'No rows should be affected!', 1
    END
END

INSERT INTO dbo.viewTest (columnA) VALUES (1)
```